# How to select dataset column from dropdown in Dash by Plotly in Python?

Tags: python, callback, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm hoping for some guidance on creating a dashboard using Dash by Plotly in Python. Although there is a lot of documentation and forums posts available online, I feel that they assume some knowledge that I may be missing, particularly in correctly using callbacks to implement interactivity.

What I am trying to achieve is a dashboard that will allow me to:

1. Upload an Excel file
2. Select a column from the Excel file
3. Run a function to process data from that column
4. Display resulting output data in a table

I have tried to create a minimal working example but have struggled. Here's what I've managed so far:

```
import base64
import io
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

## 1. Define overall dashboard layout

Dashboard = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'])
Dashboard.layout = html.Div([
                             html.H1('Dashboard Prototype', style={'width':'100%', 'textAlign': 'center'}),
                             dcc.Upload(
                                       id       = 'Dashboard_Input',
                                       children = html.A('Select Files'),
                                       style    = {'width': '100%', 'height': '60px', 'lineHeight': '60px', 'borderWidth': '1px',
                                                   'borderStyle': 'dashed', 'borderRadius': '5px', 'textAlign': 'center', 'display': 'inline-block'},
                                       multiple = True
                                       ),
                             html.Br(),
                             html.Div(id='Dashboard_Dropdown'),
                             html.Br(),
                             html.Div(id='Dashboard_Output')
                           ])

## 2. Define functions to upload, process and present data

def selectData(contents, filename, date):

    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)

    try:
        Raw_Data = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        return html.Div(['There was an error processing this file.'])

    Dropdown = html.Div([                      
                         html.H4 (('File Name: ', filename), style={'width':'100%', 'textAlign': 'center'}),
                         html.Br(),
                         dcc.Dropdown(
                                      id          = 'Dataset_and_Column',
                                      options     = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in Raw_Data.columns],
                                      style       = {'width': '100%', 'height': '60px', 'lineHeight': '60px', 'borderWidth': '1px',
                                                     'borderStyle': 'dashed', 'borderRadius': '5px', 'textAlign': 'center', 'display': 'inline-block'},
                                      placeholder =  'Select Dataset Column'
                                     ),
                         html.Br(),
                        ])

    return Dropdown

def processData(Raw_Data, Column_Label):

    # DO SOME PROCESSING THAT RESULTS IN 'TABLE':
    Table      = Table
    HTML_Table = html.Div([ 
                           dash_table.DataTable(
                                                data         = Table.to_dict('records'),
                                                columns      = [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in Table.columns],
                                                style_cell   = {'textAlign': 'center', 'width': '100px'}, 
                                                editable     = False,
                                                style_header = {'fontWeight': 'bold', 'textAlign': 'center'},
                                                style_table  = {'maxHeight': '50ex', 'width': '100%'}
                                               ),
                           html.Hr()
                         ])
    return HTML_Table

## 4. Define callback functions

Dashboard.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

@Dashboard.callback(
                    Output('Dashboard_Dropdown', 'children'),
                    [Input('Dashboard_Input'   , 'contents')],
                    [State('Dashboard_Input'   , 'filename'), State('Dashboard_Input', 'last_modified')]
                   )
def createDropdown(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
       Dropdown = [selectData(c, n, d) for c, n, d in zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
       return Dropdown

################################################################################
################################################################################

# THIS BIT DOESN'T WORK #
# Need to make this callback function take an input of Raw_Date and Column_Label (selected from the dropdown) to run the processData() function.

@Dashboard.callback(
                    Output('Dashboard_Output'  , 'children'),
                    [Input('Dataset_and_Column', 'contents'), Input('Dataset_and_Column', 'value')],
                   )
def processSelectedColumn(contents, value):

    # HTML_Table = processData(contents, value)

    return value#HTML_Table

    # ^^^^^^ Note that this allow 'value' to be printed on the dashboard but 
    # when the commented 'HTML_Table' bits are uncommented it fails

################################################################################
################################################################################

## 6. Run dashboard

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Dashboard.run_server(debug=True)
```

This allows me to select an Excel file and then print the selected column of the Pandas data frame created from it but I am unsure exactly how to connect it all together to run my `processData()` function on the selected column.

Any ideas on how I've not correctly used or connected up the callbacks, functions, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the `processSelectedColumn` callback to accept a `value` from the dropdown as an `Input` as well. It might also be possible/good to take the data from the upload as `State` instead of `Input`. That should give you the values you need to perform your desired calculation.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer:

Below are some code snippets to select a given columns from dropdown in Dash.

1. Data set `Housing price`:

   `df= pd.read_csv(r"housing_price.csv")`
2. Save columns in a variable say `options` to call in html tag of dash.

   `options = []
       for col in df.columns:
            options.append({'label':'{}'.format(col, col), 'value':col})`
3. Write a html tag for deafault `drop-down`:

`

```
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.Label("Select a feature from drop-down to plot HISTOGRAM"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id = 'my_dropdown1',
            options= options,
            value='Choose columns'
        ),
        html.Label(id='my_label1'),

        html.Button(
            id='submit-button',
            n_clicks=0,
            children='Submit',
            style={'fontSize':24, 'marginLeft':'30px'}
        )
        ])
```

4. Write the call-back:

   `@app.callback(
       Output('my_label1', 'children'),
       [Input('my_dropdown1', 'value')]
       )
   def update_dropdown(value):
       return 'You have chosen {} for histogram plot!'.format(value)`

### NOTE: If you want to use `State` follow along below code to activate call to selected column after user clicks submit button.

5. Activate `State` based callback:

   ```
   @app.callback(
       Output('my_label1', 'children'),
       [Input('submit-button', 'n_clicks')],
       [State('my_dropdown1','value')]
       )

   def update_dropdown_state(n_clicks,value):
       return 'You have chosen {} for histogram plot!'.format(value)
   ```